# Iterating over all simple unique cycles in an undirected graph in Java - brute-force approach

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, combinatorics, iterator

This post is about an `Iterator` iterating over simple loops of an undirected graph.

[image: Sample graph]

In the above graph, the cycle \$\langle 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 1 \rangle\$ is not simple, but, for example, \$S = \langle 1, 2, 3, 4, 1 \rangle\$ is. Also, note that \$ \langle 2, 3, 4, 1, 2\rangle\$ is a simple cycle too, but it encodes the same cycle as \$S\$, so we ignore it.

The algorithm is as follows:

1. Keep generating \$k\$-combinations of all the graph nodes, \$k = 3, 4, \ldots, n\$.
2. For each \$k\$-combination, permute it \$k!\$ times.
3. For each permutation of a \$k\$-combination, check whether that permutation specifies a simple cycle.
4. If the answer from Step 3 is yes, make sure that the cycle is not yet iterated over. Otherwise, continue the search.
5. If the answer from Step 4 is yes, print the permutation. Otherwise, continue the search.

Before we start, we need a facility for generating combinations:

**`com.github.coderodde.util.CombinationIterable.java`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

public class CombinationIterable<T> implements Iterable<List<T>> {

    private final List<T> allElements;
    private final int currentCombinationSize;

    public CombinationIterable(List<T> allElements, int combinationSize) {
        this.allElements = new ArrayList<>(allElements);
        this.currentCombinationSize = checkCombinationSize(combinationSize);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<List<T>> iterator() {
        return new CombinationIterator<>(allElements, currentCombinationSize);
    }

    public int getCombinationSize() {
        return currentCombinationSize;
    }

    private int checkCombinationSize(int combinationSize) {
        if (combinationSize <= 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "k is too small (" 
                            + combinationSize 
                            + "). Must be at most 1.");
        }

        if (combinationSize > allElements.size()) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "k is too large (" 
                            + combinationSize
                            + "). Must be at most " 
                            + allElements.size() 
                            + ".");
        }

        return combinationSize;
    }

    private static final class CombinationIterator<T> 
    implements Iterator<List<T>> {

        private final List<T> allElements;
        private List<T> nextCombination;
        private final int[] indices;
        private int currentCombinationSize;

        CombinationIterator(List<T> allElements, int currentCombinationSize) {
            this.allElements = new ArrayList<>(allElements);
            this.currentCombinationSize = currentCombinationSize;
            this.indices = new int[allElements.size()];
            nextCombination = new ArrayList<>(currentCombinationSize);

            for (int i = 0; i < currentCombinationSize; i++) {
                indices[i] = i;
                nextCombination.add(allElements.get(i));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return nextCombination != null;
        }

        @Override
        public List<T> next() {
            if (nextCombination == null) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("No combinations left.");
            }

            List<T> combination = nextCombination;
            generateNextCombination();
            return combination;
        }

        private void loadCombination() {
            List<T> combination = new ArrayList<>(currentCombinationSize);

            for (int i = 0; i < currentCombinationSize; ++i) {
                combination.add(allElements.get(indices[i]));
            }

            this.nextCombination = combination;
        }

        private void generateNextCombination() {
            if (indices[currentCombinationSize - 1] < indices.length - 1) {
                indices[currentCombinationSize - 1]++;
                loadCombination();
                return;
            }

            for (int i = currentCombinationSize - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
                if (indices[i] < indices[i + 1] - 1) {
                    indices[i]++;

                    for (int j = i + 1; j < currentCombinationSize; ++j) {
                        indices[j] = indices[j - 1] + 1;
                    }

                    loadCombination();
                    return;
                }
            }

            ++currentCombinationSize;

            if (currentCombinationSize > indices.length) {
                this.nextCombination = null;
                return;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < currentCombinationSize; ++i) {
                indices[i] = i;
            }

            loadCombination();
        }
    }
}
```

Permutation generator follows:

**`com.github.coderodde.util.PermutationIterable.java`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.util;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

/**
 * This class implements an {@code Iterable} returning all possible permutations 
 * of a list.
 * 
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Feb 14, 2016) :*
 */
public class PermutationIterable<T> implements Iterable<List<T>> {

    private final List<T> allElements = new ArrayList<>();

    public PermutationIterable(List<T> allElements) {
        this.allElements.addAll(allElements);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<List<T>> iterator() {
        return new PermutationIterator<>(allElements);
    }

    private static final class PermutationIterator<T> 
    implements Iterator<List<T>> {

        private List<T> nextPermutation;
        private final List<T> allElements = new ArrayList<>();
        private final int[] indices;

        PermutationIterator(List<T> allElements) {
            if (allElements.isEmpty()) {
                nextPermutation = null;
                indices = null;
                return;
            }

            this.allElements.addAll(allElements);
            this.indices = new int[allElements.size()];

            for (int i = 0; i < indices.length; ++i) {
                indices[i] = i;
            }

            nextPermutation = new ArrayList<>(this.allElements);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return nextPermutation != null;
        }

        @Override
        public List<T> next() {
            if (nextPermutation == null) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("No permutations left.");
            }

            List<T> ret = nextPermutation;
            generateNextPermutation();
            return ret;
        }

        private void generateNextPermutation() {
            int i = indices.length - 2;

            while (i >= 0 && indices[i] > indices[i + 1]) {
                --i;
            }

            if (i == -1) {
                // No more new permutations.
                nextPermutation = null;
                return;
            }

            int j = i + 1;
            int min = indices[j];
            int minIndex = j;

            while (j < indices.length) {
                if (indices[i] < indices[j] && indices[j] < min) {
                    min = indices[j];
                    minIndex = j;
                }

                ++j;
            }

            swap(indices, i, minIndex);

            ++i;
            j = indices.length - 1;

            while (i < j) {
                swap(indices, i++, j--);
            }

            loadPermutation();
        }

        private void loadPermutation() {
            List<T> newPermutation = new ArrayList<>(indices.length);

            for (int i : indices) {
                newPermutation.add(allElements.get(i));
            }

            this.nextPermutation = newPermutation;
        }
    }

    private static void swap(int[] array, int a, int b) {
        int tmp = array[a];
        array[a] = array[b];
        array[b] = tmp;
    }
}
```

A graph implementation. Mean and lean.

**`com.github.coderodde.graph.UndirectedGraph.java`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.graph;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

public class UndirectedGraph {

    protected final Map<Integer, Set<Integer>> neighborMap = new HashMap<>();

    public void addVertex(Integer vertex) {
        neighborMap.put(vertex, new HashSet<>());
    }

    public void addEdge(Integer vertexA, Integer vertexB) {
        neighborMap.get(vertexA).add(vertexB);
        neighborMap.get(vertexB).add(vertexA);
    }

    public boolean hasEdge(Integer vertexA, Integer vertexB) {
        return neighborMap.get(vertexA).contains(vertexB);
    }

    public Set<Integer> getNeighbors(Integer vertex) {
        return neighborMap.get(vertex);
    }

    public int getNumberOfVertices() {
        return neighborMap.size();
    }
}
```

The actual cycle iterator:

**`com.github.coderodde.graph.GraphCycleIterator.java`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.graph;

import com.github.coderodde.util.CombinationIterable;
import com.github.coderodde.util.PermutationIterable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * This class implements an {@link Iterable} over simple cycles in undirected
 * graphs.
 *
 * @author Rodion "rodde" Efremov
 * @version 1.6 (Aug 15, 2022)
 */
public class GraphCycleIterator implements Iterable<List<Integer>> {

    private final UndirectedGraph graph;
    private final List<Integer> nodeList;

    public GraphCycleIterator(UndirectedGraph graph) {
        this.graph = Objects.requireNonNull(graph, "The input graph is null.");
        this.nodeList = new ArrayList<>(graph.neighborMap.keySet());

        if (graph.getNumberOfVertices() < 3) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The input graph is too small.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<List<Integer>> iterator() {
        return new CycleIteratorImpl();
    }

    private final class CycleIteratorImpl implements Iterator<List<Integer>> {

        private List<Integer> nextCycle;
        private Iterator<List<Integer>> nodeCombinationIterator;
        private Iterator<List<Integer>> nodePermutationIterator;
        private final Set<Set<Integer>> cycleCacheSet = new HashSet<>();

        CycleIteratorImpl() {
            nodeCombinationIterator
                    = new CombinationIterable<>(
                            new ArrayList<>(
                                    graph.neighborMap.keySet()), 3).iterator();

            List<Integer> list = nodeCombinationIterator.next();

            nodePermutationIterator
                    = new PermutationIterable<>(list).iterator();

            generateNextCycle();
        }

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return nextCycle != null;
        }

        @Override
        public List<Integer> next() {
            if (nextCycle == null) {
                throw new NoSuchElementException("No next cycle.");
            }

            List<Integer> returnCycle = nextCycle;
            generateNextCycle();
            return returnCycle;
        }

        private void generateNextCycle() {
            mainLoop:
            while (true) {
                if (nodePermutationIterator.hasNext()) {
                    List<Integer> cycleCandidate;

                    do {
                        cycleCandidate = nodePermutationIterator.next();
                    } while (!isSimpleCycle(graph, cycleCandidate)
                            && nodePermutationIterator.hasNext());

                    if (!nodePermutationIterator.hasNext()) {
                        if (!nodeCombinationIterator.hasNext()) {
                            nextCycle = null;
                            return;
                        }

                        List<Integer> newList = nodeCombinationIterator.next();
                        nodePermutationIterator
                                = new PermutationIterable<>(newList).iterator();

                        continue mainLoop;
                    } else {
                        Set<Integer> cacheEntry = new HashSet<>(cycleCandidate);

                        if (!cycleCacheSet.contains(cacheEntry)) {
                            cycleCacheSet.add(cacheEntry);
                            nextCycle = cycleCandidate;
                            return;
                        } else {
                            continue mainLoop;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (nodeCombinationIterator.hasNext()) {
                        List<Integer> newList = nodeCombinationIterator.next();
                        nodePermutationIterator
                                = new PermutationIterable<>(newList).iterator();

                        continue mainLoop;
                    } else {
                        nextCycle = null;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static boolean isSimpleCycle(UndirectedGraph graph,
            List<Integer> cycleCandidate) {
        return isCycle(graph, cycleCandidate)
                && isSimple(graph, cycleCandidate);
    }

    private static boolean isCycle(UndirectedGraph graph,
            List<Integer> cycleCandidate) {

        for (int i = 0; i < cycleCandidate.size(); i++) {
            Integer vertexA = cycleCandidate.get(i);
            Integer vertexB = cycleCandidate.get(
                    (i + 1) % cycleCandidate.size());

            if (!graph.hasEdge(vertexA, vertexB)) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static boolean isSimple(UndirectedGraph graph,
            List<Integer> cycle) {
        Map<Integer, Integer> filterMap = new HashMap<>();
        Set<Edge> cycleEdges = convertCycleToEdgeList(cycle);

        for (var vertex : cycle) {
            filterMap.put(vertex, 0);

            for (var neighbor : graph.getNeighbors(vertex)) {
                Edge edge = new Edge(vertex, neighbor);

                if (cycleEdges.contains(edge)) {
                    if (filterMap.get(vertex) == 2) {
                        // Once here, 'cycle' is not simple.
                        return false;
                    }

                    filterMap.put(vertex, filterMap.get(vertex) + 1);
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    private static Set<Edge> convertCycleToEdgeList(List<Integer> cycle) {
        Set<Edge> edges = new HashSet<>(cycle.size());

        for (int i = 0; i < cycle.size(); i++) {
            Integer vertex1 = cycle.get(i);
            Integer vertex2 = cycle.get((i + 1) % cycle.size());
            edges.add(new Edge(vertex1, vertex2));
        }

        return edges;
    }

    private static final class Edge {

        Integer vertex1;
        Integer vertex2;

        Edge(Integer vertex1, Integer vertex2) {
            this.vertex1 = vertex1;
            this.vertex2 = vertex2;
        }

        @Override
        public int hashCode() {
            return vertex1 ^ vertex2;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object o) {
            Edge other = (Edge) o;
            return other.vertex1.equals(vertex1)
                    && other.vertex2.equals(vertex2);
        }
    }
}
```

The demo driver:

**`com.github.coderodde.graph.Demo.java`:**

```
package com.github.coderodde.graph;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

public class Demo {

    private static final int LARGE_DEMO_NUMBER_OF_VERTICES = 10;
    private static final int LARGE_DEMO_NUMBER_OF_EDGES =
            LARGE_DEMO_NUMBER_OF_VERTICES * LARGE_DEMO_NUMBER_OF_VERTICES / 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("<<< Small demo >>>");
        UndirectedGraph g = new UndirectedGraph();

        g.addVertex(1);
        g.addVertex(2);
        g.addVertex(3);
        g.addVertex(4);
        g.addVertex(5);
        g.addVertex(6);
        g.addVertex(7);

        Map<Integer, Character> m = new HashMap<>();

        m.put(1, 'A');
        m.put(2, 'B');
        m.put(3, 'C');
        m.put(4, 'D');
        m.put(5, 'E');
        m.put(6, 'F');
        m.put(7, 'G');

        g.addEdge(1, 2);
        g.addEdge(2, 3);
        g.addEdge(4, 5);
        g.addEdge(5, 6);

        g.addEdge(1, 4);
        g.addEdge(2, 5);
        g.addEdge(3, 6);

        g.addEdge(5, 7);
        g.addEdge(6, 7);

        /*
        Graph:

        A - B - C
        |   |   |
        D - E - F
             \ /
              G

        Simple cycles:

        EFG
        ABED
        BCFE
        BCFGE
        ABCFED
        ABCFGED

        */

        GraphCycleIterator graphCycleIterator = new GraphCycleIterator(g);
        int i = 1;

        for (List<Integer> encodedCycle : graphCycleIterator) {
            System.out.printf("%d: %s\n", i++, decode(encodedCycle, m));
        }

        largeDemo();
    }

    private static void largeDemo() {
        System.out.println("<<< Larger demo >>>");
        UndirectedGraph g = new UndirectedGraph();
        Random random = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < LARGE_DEMO_NUMBER_OF_VERTICES; i++) {
            g.addVertex(i);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < LARGE_DEMO_NUMBER_OF_EDGES; i++) {
            int v1 = random.nextInt(g.getNumberOfVertices());
            int v2 = random.nextInt(g.getNumberOfVertices());

            if (v1 != v2) {
                g.addEdge(v1, v2);
            }
        }

        List<List<Integer>> cycles = new ArrayList<>();
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (List<Integer> cycle : new GraphCycleIterator(g)) {
            cycles.add(cycle);
        }

        long endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Total time: " + (endTime - startTime) + " ms.");

        int lineNumber = 1;

        for (List<Integer> cycle : cycles) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%3d: %s", lineNumber++, cycle));
        }
    }

    private static String decode(List<Integer> code, Map<Integer, Character> decoderMap) {
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        for (Integer i : code) {
            stringBuilder.append(decoderMap.get(i));
        }

        return stringBuilder.toString();
    }
}
```

**Demo output**

```
<<< Small demo >>>
1: EFG
2: ABED
3: BCFE
4: BCFGE
5: ABCFED
6: ABCFGED
<<< Larger demo >>>
Total time: 792 ms.
  1: [0, 1, 3]
  2: [1, 3, 4]
  3: [1, 3, 6]
  4: [1, 6, 9]
  5: [6, 7, 9]
  6: [7, 8, 9]
  7: [0, 1, 4, 3]
  8: [0, 1, 6, 3]
  9: [0, 1, 6, 7]
 10: [0, 1, 9, 7]
 11: [0, 3, 6, 7]
 12: [1, 4, 3, 6]
 13: [1, 3, 5, 9]
 14: [1, 3, 6, 9]
 15: [1, 6, 7, 9]
 16: [2, 5, 9, 7]
 17: [3, 5, 9, 6]
 18: [6, 7, 8, 9]
 19: [0, 1, 9, 5, 3]
 20: [0, 1, 3, 6, 7]
 21: [0, 1, 9, 6, 3]
 22: [0, 3, 1, 9, 7]
 23: [0, 1, 6, 9, 7]
 24: [0, 1, 9, 8, 7]
 25: [0, 3, 5, 2, 7]
 26: [0, 3, 5, 9, 7]
 27: [0, 3, 6, 9, 7]
 28: [1, 4, 3, 5, 9]
 29: [1, 4, 3, 6, 9]
 30: [1, 3, 5, 9, 6]
 31: [1, 3, 6, 7, 9]
 32: [1, 6, 7, 8, 9]
 33: [2, 5, 3, 6, 7]
 34: [2, 5, 9, 6, 7]
 35: [2, 5, 9, 8, 7]
 36: [3, 5, 9, 7, 6]
 37: [0, 1, 3, 5, 2, 7]
 38: [0, 1, 9, 5, 2, 7]
 39: [0, 1, 4, 3, 6, 7]
 40: [0, 3, 4, 1, 9, 7]
 41: [0, 1, 6, 9, 5, 3]
 42: [0, 1, 3, 5, 9, 7]
 43: [0, 1, 3, 6, 9, 7]
 44: [0, 3, 1, 9, 8, 7]
 45: [0, 1, 6, 9, 8, 7]
 46: [0, 3, 5, 9, 6, 7]
 47: [0, 3, 5, 9, 8, 7]
 48: [0, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7]
 49: [1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 6]
 50: [1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 9]
 51: [1, 6, 7, 2, 5, 9]
 52: [1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 6]
 53: [1, 4, 3, 6, 7, 9]
 54: [1, 3, 5, 9, 7, 6]
 55: [1, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
 56: [2, 5, 3, 6, 9, 7]
 57: [3, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6]
 58: [0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7]
 59: [0, 1, 6, 3, 5, 2, 7]
 60: [0, 1, 9, 7, 2, 5, 3]
 61: [0, 1, 6, 9, 5, 2, 7]
 62: [0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 7]
 63: [0, 1, 4, 3, 6, 9, 7]
 64: [0, 3, 4, 1, 9, 8, 7]
 65: [0, 1, 3, 5, 9, 6, 7]
 66: [0, 1, 3, 5, 9, 8, 7]
 67: [0, 1, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7]
 68: [0, 3, 6, 9, 5, 2, 7]
 69: [1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7, 6]
 70: [1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7, 9]
 71: [1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 6, 9]
 72: [1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 8, 9]
 73: [1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 7, 6]
 74: [1, 4, 3, 6, 7, 8, 9]
 75: [1, 3, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6]
 76: [2, 5, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7]
 77: [0, 3, 4, 1, 9, 5, 2, 7]
 78: [0, 1, 3, 6, 9, 5, 2, 7]
 79: [0, 1, 9, 8, 7, 2, 5, 3]
 80: [0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 6, 7]
 81: [0, 1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 8, 7]
 82: [0, 1, 4, 3, 6, 9, 8, 7]
 83: [0, 1, 6, 3, 5, 9, 8, 7]
 84: [1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7, 6, 9]
 85: [1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7, 8, 9]
 86: [1, 3, 5, 2, 7, 8, 9, 6]
 87: [1, 4, 3, 5, 9, 8, 7, 6]
 88: [0, 1, 4, 3, 6, 9, 5, 2, 7]
 89: [0, 1, 6, 9, 8, 7, 2, 5, 3]
 90: [1, 4, 3, 5, 2, 7, 8, 9, 6]
```

**Critique request**

As always, please tell me anything that comes to mind.

Comment: **Define _simple_ a bit better.** ⟨1,2,3,4,5,3⟩ is probably not simple as it does not end in 1 or starts with 3 (=no cycle). ⟨1,2,3,4,5,3,1⟩ is not simple as 3 is repeated (contains an other cycle). ⟨3,4,5,3⟩ again would be simple. _Examples are good but do not make a definition self-evident._